# Расположение элемента на границы <div>

Tags: html, веб-программирование, html5, веб-дизайн

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В общем, суть в чем. Мне нужно сверстать так, как показано на рисунке, т.е элемент должен располагаться на границе. Единственное, что в голову приходит, это задать position: absolute и с помощью top, left поставить, куда надо. Но почему-то кажется, что это неправильно. Может быть есть другой способ?

Comment: иначе сделать никак не получится.

Comment: соглашусь, по-другому никак

Answer (score 3):

Вместо `position: absolute` можно использовать отрицательные маргины.

```css
div{
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
#block{
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 40px;
}
#onborder{
  height: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id='block'>
  <div id='onborder'> Оно? </div>
</div>
```

Comment: хм, думаю, это подойдет. Благодарю

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант, можно использовать fieldset, возможно его будет достаточно для решения Вашей задачи:

```html
<fieldset>
        <legend><div style="background-color:red">Какой-то блок</div></legend>
        <div>Какой-то интересный контент</div>
    </fieldset>
```

Comment: Самое адекватное решение, можно как угодно оформить - [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/5c62tnty/2/). Если элемент должен выглядеть как fieldset то это fieldset и не надо ничего придумывать.